# redirecting from IIS to tomcat?

Tags: iis, jakarta-ee, tomcat, dns, hosting

i have a hosting space in vps. where numerous domains are parked. my domain name is mywebsite.com it is present in c:\uname\mywebsite.com inside the folder there is default.aspx file. when I type in the url as www.mywebsite.com i can see default.aspx page. if i replace with any other page index.jsp i will get the error thrown by IIS server. so, I installed tomcat, java and deployed war file. I have even made changes in server.xml in  tag specifing the host name too... how can i redirect the incoming requests to tomcat server? please guide me in it

Comment: Related: [What is the recommended way of deploying a Java EE application in IIS?](https://serverfault.com/q/952154/300053) (Serverfault)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a connector. 
I would try BonCode: tomcatiis.riaforge.org

Answer (score 0):

HTTP uses port 80 for connections by default.

One network port (in this case is TCP 80 or the `http://example.com:{port}`) on each IP can only being listened to by one application.

Yours is currently used by IIS. First you need to do is check what port is used by the Tomcat (refer [here](http://www.digizol.com/2008/06/tomcat-how-to-change-port-8080.html)).

Then you should try to browse `http://example.com:{port in tomcat server.xml}` and see if you can view the Tomcat welcome page correctly or not, or your application.

After you verified that the tomcat is working, you can decide to change the Tomcat port number to whatever you want, make sure IIS is shutdown if you want to run it on 80.

Another option is to install Apache on port 80 as a proxy to connect the Tomcat port 8080, this will provide for security and flexibility if you need to extend your infrastructure in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to go to tomcat.apache.org, and download the ISAPI redirector. This communicates via AJP and you can set it up to redirect various urls to tomcat.